# Add margin between ::before and element self, only if element self is displayed

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I've been trying to solve this for a while. As an example, this code;

```
<span class="icon">save</span> lorem ipsum
<span class="icon"><span class="screenreader">edit</span></span> lorem ipsum
```

With a ::before I add an icon to the span. No problems there. Now I would like to add a margin between the icon and the 'label'. But only if there is a label displayed. For example, the 'edit' label is hidden and purely in the code for screenreaders.

An example says more than a thousand words;
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbWwbb

Notice how there's unwanted margin before lorem ipsum on the second line. How can I solve this without adding extra markup to the html?

Thanx!

Comment: i applaud your accessibility minded approach! what benefits does that span provide to screen readers? aside from hiding text visually/including text to be voiced?

Comment: Thanx! Not my idea tho, some creative borrowing from my colleagues. To my knowledge it's sole purpose is what you've just described: it's a fallback for the visually impaired who use a screenreader to turn the text into voice or braille.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add one space after pseudo-element content and remove margin-right. This will work because browser collapses multiple spaces and renders only one.

```
.icon:before {
    content: '❤ '; /* space after heart will make a trick */
}
```

So it will render as expected in both cases.

```css
.screenreader {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}
.icon {
    color: red;
}
.icon:before {
    content: '❤ ';
}
```

```html
<span class="icon">save</span> lorem ipsum
<br>
<span class="icon"><span class="screenreader">edit</span></span> lorem ipsum
```

Comment: Quick and dirty solution! Might work in specific use cases. Yet this doesn't allow for me to specify the width of the margin.

Comment: Sorry, it took me more than 5 minutes to edit the comment above (phonecall):

Quick and dirty solution! Might be the solution in specific use cases. 

Yet this doesn't allow for me to specify the width of the margin. Plus, it would always add the space. Even if it's not need, like when .icon is right aligned in a container.